# How do I compute the summation for a function from 1 to n using Racket?

Tags: racket

Summation sum(2x-1, x=1...n). I have to write a recursive function to solve the sum.

```
(define (sum1 n)
  (if (= n 0)
      -1
      (+ n (- 1 (sum1 (* n 1))))))
```

This is what I have so far, I am so lost.

Answer (score 1):

Your base case is `1` not `0` because you're only defining it from **`1`** to `n`. Therefore, the function is only defined over `N`. So we don't need to consider the `0` case for the function (it only consumes `N`s).

Furthermore, the recursive call should add n *applied* to `2x-1` to the summation of the rest of the sequence. Currently the  function does not  terminate because  you are calling it on the same input `(* n 1) = n`. `(sum1 n) => (sum1 n) => ...`

```
#lang racket

(require rackunit)

;; N is one of:
;; - 1
;; - (+ 1 N)
;; interpretation: 1, 2, 3 ...

;; N -> Number
;; sums `(- (* 2 x) 1)` from 1 to n
(define (sum1 n)
  (if (= n 1)
      (- (* 2 1) 1) ;; = 1
      (+ (- (* 2 n) 1) (sum1 (- n 1)))))

(check-equal? (sum1 1) 1)
(check-equal? (sum1 10) 100)
```

Abstracting out the function:

```
;; [Number -> Number] N -> Number
;; sums of f from 1 to n
(define (summation f n)
  (if (= n 1)
      (f 1)
      (+ (f n) (summation f (- n 1)))))

(check-equal? (summation identity 5) (+ 1 2 3 4 5))
(check-equal? (summation sqr 3) (+ (sqr 1) (sqr 2) (sqr 3)))

(check-equal? (summation (λ (x) (- (* 2 x) 1)) 1) 1)
(check-equal? (summation (λ (x) (- (* 2 x) 1)) 10) 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to output the sum, this is how I would do it:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define (sum n)
  (if (= n 1)
     1
     (+ (-(* 2 n) 1) (sum (- n 1)))))
```